# trying to implement bearer token to swaggger

Tags: c#, swagger

Im trying to add bearer authentication to swagger api, im very poor with this case and im trying to know something (im 14...) the case is that, the ApiKeyScheme is not found for me...
there is my code:

```
c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer",
                            new ApiKeyScheme { In = "header",
                            Description = "Please enter into field the word 'Bearer' following by space and JWT", 
                            Name = "Authorization", Type = "apiKey" });
                            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> {
                            { "Bearer", Enumerable.Empty<string>() },
                        });
```

And those are my libraries:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using EdictApi.Models;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System;
using System.Linq;
```

And im so confused with it, can someone calm explain me this? :)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Try to use swashbuckle.

It will make generating the swagger json easier.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @Jason Cannot find the type name or namespace "ApiKeyScheme" (no using directive or assembly reference?)

Comment: I did it @JM123 also i connected my DB to swagger and do the dotnet ef migration and it works, but now i would to add bearer to my POSTs...

Comment: I'll do my best to help as I dont use the .net core version of swashbuckle

If I understand correctly you have calls that require a Token in the header for the authentication.  

But as its not part of the Method signature it does not see it and does not generate it?

Comment: It just look like that:
https://imgur.com/a/6Iuf5kK
like i need to add something to "using" statement but i dunno what...

Comment: Im trying to add some method to authorize my requests using swagger bearer but i can't find any way to know it from internet, i can't find any tut :P

Comment: See https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/501
mrugeshparekh  said : 
// NOTE: You must also configure 'EnableApiKeySupport' below in the SwaggerUI section
                        c.ApiKey("apiKey")
                            .Description("API Key Authentication")
                            .Name("Token")
                            .In("header");

Comment: this helped me fix the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56234504/migrating-to-swashbuckle-aspnetcore-version-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Description =
                    "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer 12345abcdef\"",
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                Scheme = "Bearer"
            });
            c.IncludeXmlComments($@"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\I.Api.xml");
            c.OperationFilter<T2ParametersOperationFilter>();
            c.OperationFilter<T1ParametersOperationFilter>();
```

Comment: ibnstead of new apiSchem use OpenApiSecurity