# How to document API Key authentication using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v5.0.0-rc2

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I am migrating a Web API that has Swagger documenation generated using Swashbuckle from .NET Framework to ASP.NET Core.  In the new AspNetCore version I'm using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v5.0.0-rc2.

This is an internal service and authentication uses an API key provided in a custom HTTP header.  In the .NET Framework application, I configured Swashbuckle to enable my API key as follows:

```
c.ApiKey("apiKey")
   .Description("My description")
   .Name("MyHttpHeaderName")
   .In("header);
```

and

```
c.EnableApiKeySupport("MyHtpHeaderName", "header);
```

How can I enable support for the same API key using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v5.0.0-rc2?

Much of the information I've found by searching seems to relate to versions of Swashbuckle.AspNetCode prior to v5.0.0-rc2.

This answer is for v5.0.0-rc2 but only covers Bearer Authorization, and doesn't seem to relate to using a custom HTTP header: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57872872/13087

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore`, the authorization setup is all handled with the `AddSecurityDefinition` method.

In 4.x, you could set up an `ApiKeyScheme` that describes how to use an API key to authorize requests:

```
c.AddSecurityDefinition("ApiKey", new ApiKeyScheme()
{
    Description = "My description",
    Name = "MyHttpHeaderName",
    In = "header",
});
```

Starting with 5.x, `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` is no longer using its own models but instead relies on [`OpenAPI.NET`](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenAPI.NET). This means that the above security definition would look like this in 5.x:

```
c.AddSecurityDefinition("ApiKey", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
{
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Name = "MyHttpHeaderName",
    Description = "My description",
});
```

Note that you will also have to set up *security requirements* to configure which security definition is required for what operations. In 5.x, the syntax for that will look like this:

```
c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
{
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "ApiKey" }
        },
        new string[] { }
    }
});
```

You can read more about all this in the [documentation on security definitions and requirements](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/v5.0.0-rc2/README-v5.md#add-security-definitions-and-requirements).